# Create SharePoint server template using VMWare ESX?

Tags: vmware-esx, sharepoint

We have to do a lot of SharePoint testing.  It would be nice to be able to click a button and deploy a new virtual machine configured as a single server farm.  Does anybody have a way to do this with VMWare ESX?

You can't just copy the virtual hard drive and rename the server--SharePoint does not really like being renamed.  Is there a way to script the entire build of the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For scripting the SharePoint deployment component, you could try [SharePoint PowerShell Deploy](http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointpdeploy). I'm sure using PowerShell and STSADM together will cover this well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at lab manager
http://www.vmware.com/products/labmanager/

Awesome utility